# HTTP request data to JSON

Tags: node.js

Here is my code

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    var buffer = []

    req.on('data', chunk => {
        buffer.push(chunk)
    })

    req.on('end', () => {
        var str = Buffer.concat(buffer).toString()
    })
})
```

it return something like this:

```
----------------------------xxxxxxxxxxx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="on"

testing function
----------------------------xxxxxxxxxxxx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="target"

backend
----------------------------xxxxxxxxx--
```

how can I parse these data to JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, use [foreach](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
let object = {};
formData.forEach(function(value, key){
    object[key] = value;
});
const json = JSON.stringify(object);
```

or [ES6 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
let object = {};
formData.forEach((value, key) => object[key] = value);
const json = JSON.stringify(object);
```